# How to log into Whatsapp account on Ubuntu remote server

Tags: server, ssh, python, gui, whatsapp

I have to execute a python script on a remote Ubuntu server.
The script basically turns on a webbrowser, navigates to Whatsapp webpage, logs in and sends messages to groups.

[Edit]
The intended code is simple.

```
import pywhatkit
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+16824339813","Hello",6,10)
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Currently, there is no GUI installed on the server. Can I successfully execute the script? (Whatsapp login requires QR verification with mobile)
2. If I have to install GUI on Ubuntu, what are the minimum system requirements and how can I install it failsafe?
3. Can I run duplicate instances of the script, resulting in several whatsapp accounts on one computer?

Comment: Without details about the script, we can only guess. Perhaps you could install a headless browser. Installing a full GUI on somebody else's server could violate your terms of service and expose a lot of undesired attack surface.

Comment: I wouldn't post an illegal question here. I've got full administrative control over the VPS server. Actually I'm asked to install GUI